# JavaFX ContextMenu doesn't auto-hide

Tags: javafx, contextmenu, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX ContextMenu assigned to the right mouse button click of a scrollpane. It opens, but it doesn't close when you click outside the scrollpane. I could add another mouse event to the scrollpane in order to hide it, but that solves only 1 problem. The main problem is that when I click on any component of the scrollpane, then the context menu remains open.

Example: Open popup via right mouse button click, then click on the button. The popup menu is still open.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");

        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2);


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( 100,100,150,150);
        Button button = new Button( "Button Text");

        // create nodes
        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add( rect);
        root.getChildren().add( button);

        // create scrollpane
        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane( root);
        sp.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    contextMenu.show( sp, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
                } 
            }
        });



        // create scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 400, 400, Color.WHITE);

        // add scene to primary stage
        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

The documentation says that there's a setAutoHide method, but it doesn't work in my case:

> Specifies whether Popups should auto hide. If a popup loses focus and
>   autoHide is true, then the popup will be hidden automatically.  The
>   only exception is when owner Node is specified using
>   show(javafx.scene.Node, double, double). Focusing owner Node will not
>   hide the PopupWindow.
>
> @defaultValue false

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interacting with child elements of the parent, will get a focus to that parent. So the context menu will not hide when the button in your code is clicked.

Try these two approaches:
1) Manually manage the visibility of context menu, i.e. hide it on button click:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        contextMenu.hide();
    }
});
```

2) Use setContextMenu() instead of showing the context menu on mouse press event:

```
sp.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

Comment: The setContextMenu() function at least closes the popup again when you click outside of it, anywhere. Although I'd expect a button press AND a close of the contextpopup menu, when the menu is open and I click the button, but it's by far better than what I had before, i. e. the always-open context menu. I had the mechanism with the button action earlier, but since I have hunderds of objects on the scrollpane, that's rather not an option. setContextMenu is. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Uiuk Biy : hello can you help me with my issue? stackoverflow.com/q/27182323/2722799

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is old post, but for any newcomer I found a new solution. I have an jdk 1.8 and I have the same problem as you, but I have a dynamic generated context menu in TableView. So when you right click on the row I need another context menu by the row content. The key for my solution is that you execute show method in the context menu you pass on the window parameter to the method. Example of my code is below:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = this.createContextMenu();
contextMenu.show(this.tableView.getScene().getWindow(), mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
```

And when I click to another location of my program, the context menu hide.